# Let users edit/delete only their own content (in generic repositories)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to let users only manage their own content(edit/delete/list of things... and everything need to admin panel for their own content). In my project I use **unitOfwork** and **GenericRepositories** and i have **BaseRepositoy**  for implementing the rest of the repositories(to avoid duplicate codes); I know I must implement user repository and use it in other repositories for getting user and continuing the operation ..., but i want to know if there's any way to **implement BaseRepository**?**or another way to avoid manipulating repositories and writing duplicate code?**

```
namespace ServiceLayer.Repository
{
    public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _t;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private IQueryable<T> _db;
        protected BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _t = _unitOfWork.Set<T>();
            _db = _t;
        }
        public virtual (IQueryable<T> List, int? PageId, int? PageCount) GetAll(int? pageId, Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] searchExpression, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {


            if (includeExpressions != null && includeExpressions.Any())
            {
                foreach (var expression in includeExpressions)
                {
                    _db = _db.Include(expression);
                }
            }
            if (searchExpression != null && searchExpression.Any())
            {
                foreach (var expression in searchExpression)
                {
                    _db = _db.Where(expression);
                }
            }

            if (pageId == null) return (_db, null, null);

            if (pageId <= 0)
                pageId = 1;

            int take = 5;
            int skip = ((int)pageId - 1) * take;
            int count = _db.Count();
            int pageCount = count / take;



            var list = _db.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(skip).Take(take);
            return (list, (int)pageId, pageCount);
        }


        public virtual T Get(long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpression)
        {
            if (includeExpression == null) return _t.Find(id);

            foreach (var expression in includeExpression)
            {
                _db = _db.Include(expression);
            }
            return _db.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public virtual List<T> GetIdsArray(long?[] ids, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpression)
        {
            if (ids == null) return null;
            if (includeExpression == null) return _t.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
            foreach (var expression in includeExpression)
            {
                _db = _db.Include(expression);
            }
            return _db.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
        }

        public virtual T Update(T obj)
        {
            _unitOfWork.MarkAsChanged(obj);
            _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges();
            return obj;
        }

        public virtual T Add(T obj)
        {
            _t.Add(obj);
            _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges();
            return obj;
        }

        public virtual int Remove(T obj)
        {
            _t.Remove(obj);
            return _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges();
        }

        public virtual int RemoveIdsArray(long?[] objs)
        {
            if (objs == null || objs.Length <= 0) return -5;
            var objects = GetIdsArray(objs, null);
            foreach (var o in objects)
            {
                _t.Remove(o);
            }
            return _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges();
        }


        public virtual (string[] fieldName, IEnumerable<string> DisplayAttribute) GetAllNameAndTitleOfDbTable()
        {
            var fieldName = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                    BindingFlags.Public |
                                                    BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(property => property.Name)
                .ToArray();
            var name = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                               BindingFlags.Public |
                                               BindingFlags.Instance).Select(property =>
                ((DisplayAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault())
                ?.Name).ToArray();
            return (fieldName, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Something I've done in the past is to create an IOwnedEntity interface

```
public interface IOwnedEntity
{
    string EntityOwner { get; set;  }
}
```

which is then implemented by my models.

```
public string EntityOwner
{
    get { return Owner; }
    set { Owner = value; }
}
```

Then in your repository you can check if T is owned and filter accordingly

```
private bool EntityIsOwnedByOwner(T entity)
{
    return (entity as IOwnedEntity).EntityOwner == CurrentLoggedOnUserID;
}
```

Obviously this will all need a bit of work to get functioning in your example, but the approach should be sound.